# What is the cardinality of $\{1,1,2\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the cardinality of $\{1,1,2\}$? Is it $2$ or $3$?

Comment: Two. In set theory there is no multiplicity **unless** specifically remarked.

Comment: Two slight variations of this question that might be good to think about as exercises: what is the cardinality of $\{1,\{1\},2\}$? Also, what is the cardinality of $\{1,\{1,2\}\}$?

Comment: The main point is $\{a\}\neq a$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $\{1,1,2\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ have the same elements, $1$ and $2$. Therefore the two sets are equal, and have cardinality $2$.

Comment: This is the model answer.

Answer (score 5):

$$\{1,1,2\}=\{1,2\}$$
Since a set contains **distinct elements**. Hence, the cardinality is $2$.

Answer (score 3):

The set $\{1,1\}$ is equivalent to the singleton set $\{1\}$, since the $1$'s are not distinct elements. Therefore, $$\{1,1,2\}=\{1,2\}$$and so the cardinality of $\{1,1,2\}$ is $2$.